# Instr function used in an if statement to find text in a row

Tags: excel, vba

In this code I am trying to have the user select a range in a row. If the row contains "HOL" the message box show will show a  message.

The way the code is right now when the user chooses one cell that contains "HOL" the message appears when the user chooses multi cells in a row an error Runtime error 13 appears.  This is the if statement that I am having problems

I have tried different range select methods but I am not familiar enough with coding yet to understand my error.

```
' Highlight_SKL Macro
' This macro will highlight leave dates for entry

Dim rng As Range

Set rng = Range(Selection.Address)

If MsgBox("Are you sure you want to submit day of SKL", vbYesNo) = vbNo  Then Exit Sub

If InStr(Range(Selection.Address), "HOL") Then MsgBox ("You are entering a SKL date on a Federal Holiday")

With Selection.Interior
    rng = "=1"
      .Pattern = xlSolid
      .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
      .Color = 250
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With
End Sub
```

When the user select a row that contains "HOL" a message box appears and lets them know.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Use a wildcard MATCH for a selection of one or many cells.

```
If Not IsError(application.match("*HOL*", Selection, 0)) Then _
    MsgBox "You are entering a SKL date on a Federal Holiday"
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code use for each loop to loop each cell of the selection to avoid errors.

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim rng As Range, cell As Range

    Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Selection.Address) '<- Change sheet name if need

    If MsgBox("Are you sure you want to submit day of SKL", vbYesNo) = vbNo Then Exit Sub

    For Each cell In rng

        If InStr(cell, "HOL") Then MsgBox ("You are entering a SKL date on a Federal Holiday")

        With cell

            With .Interior
                .Pattern = xlSolid
                .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                .Color = 250
                .TintAndShade = 0
                .PatternTintAndShade = 0
            End With

            .Value = 1

        End With

    Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: Great thank you very much for these suggestions I will give a try and report back